# Simple confusion about parallel resistors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

that tension generator has 1V , Can i just ignore it and apply the parallel resistors theorem R= R1R2/R1 + R2 ? and replace R1 and R2 by R?

if the generator wasn't there this would be easy

Comment: What are you looking for?  Voltage across AB?  Equivalent resistance? ??

Comment: Please consider asking your circuit questions over at the electrical engineering SE site as there is a schematic editor 'built-in' for both questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you're trying to do.

If you're trying to find the voltage between A and B, then note that the circuit can be redrawn as

[image]

From this redrawn circuit, it's clear that the resistors need to be treated as being in series in the process of calculating the voltage between A and B.

But if you're trying to find the [Thévenin equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem) resistance $R_{Th}$ or [Norton equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton%27s_theorem) resistance $R_{No}$ between terminals A and B, the procedure is to find the resistance between A and B after replacing the voltage source with a short circuit.  In this case, the resistors are treated as being in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.  You have $V_A-V_B$ across $R_2$, so can calculate the current in that leg.  You have $(V_A-1)-V_B$ across $R_1$, so can calculate the current in that leg.  Adding the currents will give the current into/out of $A,B$